# Searchview with customlistview and ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>

Tags: android, searchview

Hello I have implemented Custom list-view in my android project and now I want to implement search functionality on listview how can i achive that..

I didnt get how to search listview and update listview respective to query on same arraylist

Comment: Piece of info- When you are asking a question don't just post long lines of code, instead, add a few lines telling what the code does, before each file of code.

Answer (score 0):

Use ArrayList of Model class instead of Hashmap.

```
    private class DataModel{
    String userName;
    String emailAdd;
    int age;
    }

    public class DataAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        ArrayList<DataModel> data;
ArrayList<DataModel> filterData;
        LayoutInflater lat = getLayoutInflater();
        private Context context;
        Typeface custom_font;

        public DataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
            this.context = context;
            data = arraylist;
            Log.d("DATA", data.toString());
           filterData = new ArrayList(data.size());

        }

public void filter(String searchQuery){
for(DataModel model : filterData){
if(model.userName.equals(searchQuery)){
 filterData.add(model);
}
}
notifidatasetchanged();
}

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
                return filterData.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            convertView = lat.inflate(R.layout.inflate_chooselab, null);
    }
    }
```

Hope you get idea, I haven't try code, post your query if any.